# Application configuration best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture

I have a several MVC project's (all the same) and I'm wondering where to place the Application Configuration? Right now I have the following options:

- Store them in a central database
- Store them in the application database
- Store them in the appSettings (web.config)
- Store them in a configsection
- Store them in a custom configuration file

I wonder what the best practice is for a situation like this

Answer (score 0):

I think you must store them in application databse. Cuz,

- It will be different for every application, e.g. If one application light theme and the other wants dark theme.
- It is better to save in databse, cuz you can update the configuration by application itself or by running a query. So, its very to simple to  change the settings rather than keeping it in Web.Config.
- You can create a class to acces the configuration values from database. use Indexer so that you can use it like `Configuration["Theme"]` makes the access more easier. I have used it in my project.

But, if its database related, you need to store it in web.config

Hope, it helps you lil bit. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is really a common 'best practice' for *where* to store settings. You would have to take into consideration all the variables for a given situation. Some thoughts I had:

- Storing settings in a database could be useful if you require central storage between different applications. Would have fewer concurrency issues. Depending on the type of settings stored, you could find database schemas being inefficient. It also brings in a dependency on another server/service for the application.
- Storing in web.config is nice and simple. Not really useful for settings that need to be changeable from the application. Also, any change to settings in web.config will initiate an app restart.
- Custom configuration file would give more flexibility for setting storage. You will of course have to write additional code to read/write the settings. Serialisation could handle this in a lot of cases.

If it's low-level application settings that are changed rarely and only by you, I'd probably go for just web.config. If you're talking about settings that are changed through the application (e.g. user preferences), I'd go for database storage.

Answer (score 0):

You should store default values in `web.config` and other settings in your `database`.

For example if your application has a `mailing system`, than `smtp settings` should be stored in your database, but the culture in which mails are sent should be stored in `web.config`

Also, there is a way to store **application settings**  in your `Visual Studio` environment, as follows

`Right click on your project > Properties > Settings tab > Create`

but I've never used this. You can also update your settings by calling `.Save()` method. Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28ApplicationSettingsOverview%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29&rd=true)

In my case :

- I store settings in my database
- I store default values in `web.config`

Answer (score 0):

Configuration is something which one should quickly locate, that is why there are configuration files in projects irrespect to platform. Every platform sdk now comes with SDK which ensures their community follows practices they recommend.

If you want to secure configuration files, you can encrypt it which i believe not needed if the software development follows subversion workflows and other development practices.